# usage of "get the sense of" in a sentence

Tags: expressions, vocabulary

What does this sentence actually means? this is from the book ***Born to Run***:

> Imagine Anderson Cooper vanishing on assignment for CNN, and you get the sense of the search that was launched for Bierce. But no trace was ever found.

Comment: One could substitute 'get a good picture of', 'get a good mental image of', 'well imagine', 'easily see',  'clearly envisage' (though I'm not saying that these might not be in poorer style).

Comment: I couldn't understand the whole sentence yet!

Comment: Sorry, nada. Requests for help with the _comprehension_ of sentences is off-topic (proofreading or 'too general', ie no specific construction or word identified). Literature.SE has a 'meaning' tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is likening the search for Cooper to the search for Bierce..."get the sense of" in this case means to grasp the characteristics of something. In this case it seems that the author tries to convey the scale of the search that was launched for Bierce by comparing it with the hypothetical scenario of a search for a missing news anchor.